# How Do I make Perfect Rotating Loop?

Tags: animation

I am working on an animation where my character is a donut that spins to move like a wheel. I want to make it that the animation makes the donut spin perfectly and it loops perfectly. However when I attempt to make the animation, it always rotates 360 degrees but then at the end of the animation is comes to a slow halt. I don't want this. I want it to be forever traveling at the same speed so the loop is seamless. I am fairly new to this so help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Use Constant Interpolation to make seamless animation loop.